# Dynamically Describing Mathematical Rules

Tags: c++, math

I want to be able to specify mathematical rules in an external location to my application and have my application process them at run time and perform actions (again described externally). What is the best way to do this?

For example, I might want to execute function `MyFunction1()` when the following evaluates to `true`:

`(a < b) & MyFunction2() & (myWord == "test")`.

Thanks in advance for your help.

(If it is of any relevance, I wish to use C++, C or C++/CLI)

Comment: I think you meant `&&`, not `&`.

Comment: @celtschk I'm using logic symbols rather than C/C++ syntax

Comment: Of course the logic symbol for *and* is ∧. And the mathematical sign for equality is =, not ==.

Comment: @celtschk This is a bit out of my area of expertise but my understanding is that there are a number of different symbolic logic representations. In first year electrical engineering we were taught to use AND and &, so I did. Regarding '==', that was a mistake :)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I'd consider not reinventing the wheel --- use an embedded scripting engine. This means you'd be using a standard form for describing the actions and logic. There are several great options out there that will probably be fine for your needs.

Good options include:

1. Javascript though google v8. (I don't love this from an embedding point of view, 
    but javascript is easy to work with, and many people already know it)
2. Lua. Its fast and portable. Syntax is maybe not as nice as Javascript, but embedding is
    easy.
3. Python. Clean syntax, lots of libraries. Not much fun to embed though.

I'd consider using SWIG to help generate the bindings ... I know it works for python and lua, not sure about v8.

Comment: Python is pretty easy to embed if you use Boost.Python.

Comment: @PaulManta I had some trouble with boost.python previously. Mostly that was with trying to embed a python interpreter into a C++ application (and not the other way around, which seems to be more common). Though that was years ago and things may have improved since.

Comment: Something probably changed over the years. I've been using Boost to embed Python in my C++ application over the past months and I haven't run into any problems with the library.

Comment: My reading has lead me to "mathematical language parsers" as the solution. I don't understand how JavaScript could be used in place to execute actions based on logic expressions. Would you please elaborate?

Comment: @JonaGik So long as you expose the right pieces (`a`, `b`, `MyFunction2` etc) to the language engine your condition would look like this in JavaScript `if((a < b) && MyFunction2() && (myWord == "test")) { MyFunction1(); }`. I think it'll be hard to get something more succinct.

Answer (score 1):

I would look at the [command](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Command_pattern) design pattern to handle calling external mathematical predicates, and the [Factory](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Factory_method_pattern) design pattern to run externally defined code.

Answer (score 0):

If your mathematical expression language is that simple then uou could define a grammar for it, e.g.:

```
expr = bin-op-expr | rel-expr | func-expr | var-expr | "(" expr ")"

bin-op = "&" | "|" | "!"
bin-op-expr = expr bin-op expr

rel-op = "<" | ">" | "==" | "!=" | "<=" | ">="
rel-expr = expr rel-op expr

func-args = "(" ")"
func-expr = func-name func-args

var-expr = name
```

and then translate that into a grammar for a parser. E.g. you could use Boost.Spirit which provides a DSL to allow you to express a grammar within your C++ code.

Answer (score 0):

If that calculation happens at an inner loop, you want high performance, you cannot go with scripting languages. Based on how "deployable" and how much platform independent you would like that to be:

1) You could express the equations in C++ and let g++ compile it for you at run-time, and you could link to the resulting shared object. But this method is very much platform dependent at every step! The necessary system calls, the compiler to use, the flags, loading a shared object (or a DLL)... That would be super-fast in the end though, especially if you compile the innermost loop with the equation. The equation would be inlined and all.

2) You could use java in the same way. You can get a nice java compiler in java (from Eclipse I think, but you can embed it easily). With this solution, the result would be slightly slower (depending on how much template magic you want), I would expect, by a factor of 2 for most purposes. But this solution is extremely portable. Once you get it working, there's no reason it shouldn't work anywhere, you don't need anything external to your program. Another down side to this is having to write your equations in Java syntax, which is ugly for complex math. The first solution is much better in that respect, since operator overloading greatly helps math equations.

3) I don't know much about C#, but there could be a solution similar to (2). If there is, I know that there's operator overloading in C#, so your equations would be more pleasant to write and look at.